# How do I add a query to a get request with HTML?

Tags: html

I have made this:

```
<form action="links.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="link" value="" style="height:25px;length:0px;font-size:8pt;"><br>
Direct: <input type="submit"><br>
Show: <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Is there any way I can pass a parameter when I press a different button? When I click now it sends me to `links.php?link=` which is good, but I want to do so that if I click one of the buttons, it sends me to `links.php?link=&up=no`.

I think I found a solution but it uses javascript, I want to do it with HTML only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to add a parameter based on what submit button was pressed, you can add a name to each of them:

```
<form action="links.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="link" value="" style="height:25px;length:0px;font-size:8pt;"><br>
Direct: <input type="submit" name="direct"><br>
Show: <input type="submit" name="show">
</form>
```

Pressing the `direct` submit button will give:

```
?link=&direct=...
```

Pressing the `show` button will give:

```
?link=&show=...
```

**edit**

In the event that you want to pass a specific value for each button (which isn't tied to it's text like a submit input is), use the `button` tag instead of the `input` tag and pass it explicitly:

```
<form action="links.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="link" value="" style="height:25px;length:0px;font-size:8pt;"><br>
Direct: <button name="direct" value="foo">Submit</button><br>
Show: <button name="name" value="bar">Submit</button>
</form>
```

which would result in: `?link=&direct=foo` and `?link=&show=bar`